# trying to include script in pug and call a function from the script, getting "unexpected token" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a pug template where I want to call a function with some variables passed from the endpoint that renders the page:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    button(type = 'button' onclick='play(#{x},#{y})')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='../public/javascripts/play.js')
```

Here is `play.js`:

```
const play = function(x,y){
    console.log(x+y);
}
```

When I load the page, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'     play.js:1
```

How can I get pug to include the script correctly so that I can call the function with a button click?

EDIT: here's the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="play(#{x},#{y})"></button><script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascripts/play.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

I changed the interpolation to

```
onclick=`play(${x},${y})`
```

and this renders as:

```
onclick="play(2,3)"
```

which are the values that were passed in from the endpoint, but I'm still getting the `unexpected token` error.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like (use _View page source_ in your browser)?

Comment: @phil just added it to the OP

Comment: Doesn't look like your `x` and `y` vars are interpolating correctly

Comment: See https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation

Comment: @phil fixed the interpolation but still getting the same `unexpected token` error

Comment: I ran the code in your question in my own app (but with path to play.js set to my location of play.js) and everything ran fine. `Unexpected token` is usually a parsing error by pug, ie something that breaks pug syntax. A `'` or `"` in your variables `x` or `y` would cause that. Do you have any non-visible characters in your code?

Comment: I am curious why the `src` path to your play.js is `../public/javascript`. Your stylesheet reference suggests you have a folder set up for static files. If that is correct, then it should be `src='/javascript/play.js'`. Whatever it is, the contents of play.js shouldn't cause that error as it is loaded by the client, long after pug has finished processing on the server.

Comment: @OldGeezer your diagnosis of the path issue turned out to be correct.  However, I still can't attach the event listener, and I'm going to post a new question with updated code.

Comment: @OldGeezer if you're curious, the new question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040543/parameters-in-pug-template-not-available-for-onclick-event)