# Parameters in Pug template not available for onclick event

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a pug template `test.pug` that has a button.  When clicked, I want the button to call a function that uses parameters passed to the template from the rendering endpoint.  Here is the template:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type="text/javascript").
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            document.getElementById('play-button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
                console.log(testvar);
                console.log('ready');
            });
        }, false);
  body
    button(type = 'button' id = 'play-button') Click to play
```

And here is the endpoint that renders the pug template:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    res.render('test',{
        title:'Player',
        testvar:'testvar'       
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But when I load the page and click the button, I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: testvar is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

The code works correctly if I comment out `console.log(testvar)`, so I know that the onclick event handler is being added successfully. So apparently the event handler is being added before the parameters are passed to the template.

How can I make the parameters accessible to the onclick event?

Answer (score 2):

Local variables passed through Express's `.render()` method are only available  to Pug and only available while Pug is being compiled on the server. They don't remain available to client-side javascript once Pug has been compiled to HTML and sent to the browser.

If you want them available client-side, you must use [Pug interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) to define the variable within a `script` tag, alongside your other client-side javascript.

Assuming `testvar` is a string, you could approach it like this:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type="text/javascript").
      const testvar = '#{testvar}'; // interpolate the value from Pug
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('play-button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
          console.log(testvar);
          console.log('ready');
        });
      }, false);
  body
    button(type = 'button' id = 'play-button') Click to play
```

If `testvar` is an array or object, you'll need to use the `JSON.stringify()` method to print the array or object into the `script` tag.

Comment: I don't exactly understand how to use `JSON.stringify()` in the case that `testvar` is an object.  I tried passing in an object and then calling `const testvarStr = JSON.stringify(testvar)`, and that gave the error `ReferenceError: testvar is not defined`

Comment: I figured that out, but if `testvar` is an object with methods, those methods don't get included in the `JSON.stringify` result so they can't be called within the rendered page.  Trying to figure out how to work around this...

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `JSON.stringify()` to pass it.
ex.

```
input(type="button" class = "button" value= "Download" id="Download" name="dlbtn" onclick=`_Download(${JSON.stringify(file)})`)
```

I hope that helped cause i was having that same issue